# sudoku solution check in android

Tags: java, android, sudoku

I'm very new to Android and Java development. I'm trying to create a very basic 4x4 sudoku app. However, the UI crashes when I run the code. I'm not sure which part of the code is incorrect.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level1);
    findviewbyidfunc();

    checksol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
        setmatrix();    
        ans=check(mat);
        dispsol();      
        }
    });
}

public void findviewbyidfunc()
{
            checksol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.checksol1);
    r11=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r1c1);
    r21=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r2c1);
    r31=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r3c1);
    r41=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r4c1);

    r12=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r1c2);
    r22=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r2c2);
    r32=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r3c2);
    r42=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r4c2);

    r13=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r1c3);
    r23=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r2c3);
    r33=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r3c3);
    r43=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r4c3);

    r14=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r1c4);
    r24=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r2c4);
    r34=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r3c4);
    r44=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.r4c4);

    displayanswer=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
}
```

**Code to set the matrix.**

```
public void setmatrix()
{
    //Column one
    mat[1][1]=Integer.parseInt(r11.getText().toString());
    mat[2][1]=Integer.parseInt(r21.getText().toString());
    mat[3][1]=Integer.parseInt(r31.getText().toString());
    mat[4][1]=Integer.parseInt(r41.getText().toString());
    //Column two
    mat[1][2]=Integer.parseInt(r12.getText().toString());
    mat[2][2]=Integer.parseInt(r22.getText().toString());
    mat[3][2]=Integer.parseInt(r32.getText().toString());
    mat[4][2]=Integer.parseInt(r42.getText().toString());
    //Column three
    mat[1][3]=Integer.parseInt(r13.getText().toString());
    mat[2][3]=Integer.parseInt(r23.getText().toString());
    mat[3][3]=Integer.parseInt(r33.getText().toString());
    mat[4][3]=Integer.parseInt(r43.getText().toString());
    //Column four
    mat[1][4]=Integer.parseInt(r14.getText().toString());
    mat[2][4]=Integer.parseInt(r24.getText().toString());
    mat[3][4]=Integer.parseInt(r34.getText().toString());
    mat[4][4]=Integer.parseInt(r44.getText().toString());

}
```

**Code to validate the matrix.**

```
public boolean check(Integer arr[][])
{
    Integer[] count={0,0,0,0,0};
    Integer[] count1={0,0,0,0,0};
    Boolean b=true;
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(count[arr[j][i]]>i)
            {
                b=false;
                return b;
            }
            if(count1[arr[i][j]]>i)
            {
                b=false;
                return b;
            }
            count1[arr[i][j]]++;
            count[arr[j][i]]++;     
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

If I remove the listener code and its associated function, the interface works fine. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: The LogCat tells you where you made a mistake. Post your logCat error.

Comment: Edit your post and post it there, not here.

Comment: Thanks ... Posted the LogCat errors ..

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
10-20 03:16:08.695: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.example.sudokunew.Level1_play.findviewbyidfunc(Level1_play.java:53)`  Mike M has the right answer.

Comment: Changed the TextView to EditText.. But I'm still seeing errors..

Comment: @user2899503 Its probably because you are `checksol` is `null`. You need to do a `findViewById` for `checksol` before trying to access it.

Comment: @Varun: You were right.. I've modified the code but I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Please don't change the question. Only add new information. The answers now bear no relationship to the logcat. **Please** learn how to read the logcat and Google **before** asking questions. `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4` is a very simple problem.  Google for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  the next line tells you where the problem is `at com.example.sudokunew.Level1_play.setmatrix(Level1_play.java:63)`  If you still can't fix it, come back and ask a **new** question.  Learning how to help yourself is 32,645,848 times more valuable than StackOverflow.

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for your valuable insights. I figured out the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or more of your **EditText** widgets are being declared as **TextView** in **level1.xml**. Probably **displayanswer**.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion
use "try-catch" in "setmatrix" method, for example:

```
try
{
mat[1][1]=Integer.parseInt(r11.getText().toString());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
mat[1][1]=0;
}
```